# Configurable product with limited values

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have a configurable product which involves a date and a time.
There are some restriction on these that are only known at the time of the customer request.

When displaying the product, how would I go about finding the valid configurations, and displaying only these in the frontend?

I'm using Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getAllowProducts`.
by default this method retrieves all the available (active) simple products of a configurable product.
You can inject you logic in this method and filter your the products that don't match your date conditions.